# How do I save a Docusign document to disk using the DocuSign NodeJS SDK?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, node-streams, docusign-sdk

I'm using [DocuSign eSignature NodeJS client](http://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-node-client/index.html) to download a DocuSign document and save it to disk. The [eSignature API docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) states *"by default, the response is the PDF file as a byte stream"*, which I'm getting however when I write it to the disk, the PDF viewer (i.e., macOS's Preview) states it cannot open it and that the PDF file may be damaged. I can view and download the PDF document via the DocuSign UI just fine.

```js
import * as docusign from 'docusign-esign';
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

// assume dsApiClient has been set up
const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);

(async () => {
  const data = await envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
  await writeFile('docusign.pdf', data);
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the byte stream to a raw binary stream, and then writing that to disk worked for me:

```js
import { Buffer} from "buffer";
// other code...
await writeFile('docusign.pdf', Buffer.from(data, "binary"));
```